# PHP Solr connection issue

Tags: php, solr

I have PHP-Solr extension version 1.0.3-alpha installed on my server. I'm initializing the connection using:

```
$options = array(
         'hostname' => 'hostname',
         'login'    => '',
         'password' => '',
         'port'     => '',
         'path'     => 'solr/core1');

$client = new SolrClient($options);
```

It returns the following object:

```
class SolrClient#17 (1) { private $_hashtable_index => int(13444) }
```

But whenever I try to run a query like:

```
$qryArray = 'key_id:123456';
$client->deleteByQuery($qryArray);
```

It throws an exception as follows:

> Solr HTTP Error 7: 'Couldn't connect to server

Can anyone help me to find what would causing this issue?

I have tried `var_dump($client->getDebug());`, but it returns `NULL`.

Comment: Are you missing the port while building the url..?  Or check your solr is up through browser

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Actually we have masked the port number (8983), so that we can access the solr server even without port number. BTW, I have tried by adding port number in the `$options` array. It also returns the same error. And Yes, the Solr is up through the browser.

Comment: Did you happen to find a fix for this @RJAnoop? I've got the exact same problem, returns the same object and getDebug() also dumping NULL. I can access it on the web but get the same exception trying to connect